# Shortcode in Wordpress causing php below to not function

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written a shortcode to display the posts of a custom post type (containing team member profiles) in a post with the same category assigned to specific team members. The shortcode works perfectly but the php functions (specifically the first if statement) I have in my page template below the content no longer function. Strangely if I remove the first if statement the php below the content displays correctly

My shortcode is:

```
function team_embed() {
ob_start();
global $post;
// get the domain page category
$pagecat = get_the_category();
$CategoryName = $pagecat[0]->cat_name;
$slug = $pagecat[0]->slug;
$slug1 = $pagecat[0]->slug;
$exp = '_experience';
$experience = $slug1 .= $exp;
$query = array( 'post_type' => 'team', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category_name' => $slug );
$loop = new WP_Query($query);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $phone = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Phone Number', true);
    $linkedin = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Linkedin', true);
    ?>
    <div class="team-embed-wrapper">
        <div class="team-embed">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <div class="team-embed-thumbnail">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
            <div class="team-embed-excerpt">
                <?php
                    if ($phone) { ?>
                        Phone:&nbsp;<?php echo $phone; ?><br /> <?php }
                    else {}     
                    if ($linkedin) {
                        echo $linkedin; ?><br /> <?php }
                    else {} ?>
                <br />
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="rm-button">Read Complete Profile</a>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-embed-experience">
            <strong><?php echo $CategoryName; ?> domain related experience:</strong><br />
            <p><?php echo get_field( $experience ); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>  
<?php       
endwhile;
$output = ob_get_clean();       
return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'Team_Embed', 'team_embed' );
```

The code below the page content in my page template (which works when not using the shortcode is:

```
<!-- Add closures and Case Studies if available -->
<?php
    // get the category
    $category = get_the_category();
    $firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
<?php if( get_field('tclosure_add') == 'yes' ): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $firstCategory; ?> closures</h2>
    <div class="closure-cat">
    <?php echo do_shortcode("[pt_view id=1723554lt4 cat='$firstCategory' limit=3]"); ?>
    <a class="rm-button" href="/experience">View All Company Closures</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( get_field('case_studies_add') == 'yes' ): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $firstCategory; ?> Case Studies</h2>
    <div class="case-study-embed-wrapper">
        <?php echo do_shortcode("[pt_view id=2c2b5b7ulr cat='$firstCategory' limit=3]"); ?>
    </div>
    <a class="rm-button" href="/representative-engagements/#case-studies">View All Company Case Studies</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be messing with your main query which is messing with the page template code.

You can either use a foreach on the posts

```
<?php foreach( $loop->posts as $post ): ?>
    <!-- Gather info here, remember that the $post is not global so you will have to use functions that can accept a post ID... -->
<?php endforeach;
```

or you can use `wp_reset_query()` at the end of the loop.

```
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    // .....
endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I knew it would be something simple like that. I had tried the wp_reset_query(); but I had placed it after the return $output; line.
Placing it right after the endwhile; as you showed worked perfectly.
Thanks again, I've been fighting with this for a few days now.